# run a nodejs application and its plugins as a systemd service

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, systemd

I am trying to create a service for a nodejs application having plugins.
when I start the service the application works fine but its plugins are not loaded.
And when I run the application from command line the plugins are loaded.

```
[Unit]
Description=Openveo-app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=teleco
WorkingDirectory=/home/teleco/appfolder
ExecStart=/home/teleco/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node /home/teleco/appfolder/server.js
Environment=PATH=/home/teleco/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=3000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The command `systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/app.service`doesn't give any message, so it's not a permission issue

Comment: You may be better served wrapping this up in a script and then referencing the script in your systemd service file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by integrating the plugins in the parent application folder